# How to fix this theos error?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos

When making a package install I am faced with the following error...

```
/opt/theos is not writable. Please run `/opt/theos/bin/bootstrap.sh substrate` manually, with privileges.
make: *** [before-all] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

Comment: @meda When I use sudo make the compile says like ' theos/makefiles/common.mk:4: *** Do not use 'sudo make'.  Stop.'

Comment: @frank what are you compiling

Comment: @meda a tweak file with .mx format.

Comment: @meda I figured it out .I miss one step when install theos. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the mobile terminal type su then type alpine , try the make again

Answer (score 0):

Do what it says. Run "sudo /opt/theos/bin/bootstrap.sh substrate" in terminal